linear elasticity equation and spectral equivalence
Consider
$$\nabla  \cdot \sigma = f  \quad \text{in} \quad \Omega \\
\sigma = 2\mu\varepsilon(u) + \lambda ( \nabla \cdot u ) I \quad \text{in} \quad \Omega \\
u = 0 \quad \text{over} \quad \Gamma_D \\
\sigma  \cdot n = g \quad \text{ over } \quad \Gamma_N,$$
where $\varepsilon(u) = \frac{1}{2}(\nabla u + \nabla u^T)$.
We can get the following weak formulation:
$$a(u,v) = 2\mu\int_{\Omega} (\varepsilon (u) : \varepsilon (v)) dx+ \lambda\int_{\Omega}  \; (\nabla \cdot u) (\nabla \cdot v) \;
dx\\
f(v) = \int_{\Gamma_N} g \cdot v,$$
and then the linear system $Ax = b$.

In this post, Ashkan's answer suggested that the block diagonal of the matrix $A$ is spectrally equivalent to $A$. (Each block represents the couplings along the same dimensional $(x, y, z)$, i.e. $A_{xx}, A_{yy}, A_{zz}.)$
My question is:
How can one derive the spectral equivalence from Korn's inequality?
